# Bash - Input to a while loop

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

kommando="java -jar '/home/git/yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar'"
gitdir='/home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/gitosis-export/dev/www/res/'

echo "Vil Du versionere ? (ja/nej)"
read yesno
    if [yesno="ja"]
then
    echo "Hvad vil du kalde denne version:"
read version 
else
    echo "ok - surethang !"

while
  IFS=$'\n' read linje
do
  case "$linje" in
    *.css )
      $kommando "$gitdir/$linje" --type css >> "$gitdir/`basename \"$linje\" .css`."version".css" ;;
    *.js  ) 
      $kommando "$gitdir/$linje" --type js  >> "$gitdir/`basename \"$linje\" .js`."version".js" ;;
    ?*)
  esac 
done < manifest.conf
```

when i run the script it gives me and error at line 36 (end) (when i serve the manifest to the while loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see following errors in your code:

- you not enclose `if` statement by `fi`
- missed spaces in `if` header
- use `$` when you wanted to get variable value

So, instead of

```
read yesno
if [yesno="ja"]
then
    echo "Hvad vil du kalde denne version:"
    read version 
else
    echo "ok - surethang !"
```

you should write

```
read yesno
if [ $yesno = "ja" ]
then
    echo "Hvad vil du kalde denne version:"
    read version 
else
    echo "ok - surethang !"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You have at least stray `?*)` with no terminating `;;`. Also, the `[yesno="ja"]` comaprison is wrong, you lost one dollar and due to the dollar shortage cut down on space program. Try `[[ "$yesno" = "ja" ]]` instead.

Otherwise description of the error might be helpful.

Comment: Could you explain a little further what you mean ?

Comment: Did you write the code yourself? What is `?*)` supposed to mean? What is it supposed to do in this case?